# Why is this error happening? Class 'FPDF' not found -- typo3-flow

Tags: php, fatal-error, fpdf, typo3-flow

The error happens when warming up caches and is in full:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FPDF' not found in /home/shop/public_html/releases/20150122171219/Packages/Sites/Mystuff.ModelSite/Classes/Mystuff/ModelSite/Service/InvoiceService.php on line 14
Uncaught Exception
 Execution of subprocess failed with exit code 255 without any further
 output. (Please check your PHP error log for possible Fatal errors)

More Information
 Exception code      #1355480641
 File                /home/shop/public_html/releases/20150122171219/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Core/Booting/Scripts.php line 531
 Exception reference #201504011936306ce58c
```

I've seen this error before and got around it but can't for the life of me remember how nor can I find the notes I'm sure I made about it.  Driving me crazy.  What is weird is that the live server gets this error but not my dev server, which is a copy of the live one.  The fpdf.php is there.

Thanks

Comment: Try increasing the memory allocated to PHP.

Comment: Where there any fatal errors in your php error log?

Comment: This error seems to have gone away now after another problem in our code was discovered and fixed.  Basically there was a mix up  in out git repo that had gummed up the works - exactly what part of the corruption caused this particular problem is unknown - maybe some bad package or class references..